# G code M code CNC syntax for VI & EMACS

Tags: vim, emacs, vi, cnc

I want to use Vim and EMACS for CNC, G codes & M codes.

Is there any syntax or modes for Vim or EMACS for working with this type of code?

Comment: http://pixpopuli.blogspot.com/2011/01/syntax-highlighting-for-cnc-g-code.html

Comment: Why is this being voted for closing? It is a perfectly reasonable request, from how I understand the FAQ.

Comment: Taylor - My condolences for having to write it by hand :/ What flavour are you using?

Comment: @ldigas just starting. I have a CNC handbook I'm going to be using

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some quick searching led me to [this](http://wiki.linuxcnc.org/cgi-bin/emcinfo.pl?action=browse&diff=1&id=Highlighting_In_Vim) syntax highlighting file for vim and [this](http://pixpopuli.blogspot.com/2011/01/syntax-highlighting-for-cnc-g-code.html) one for emacs. For vim the `ngc.vim` file needs to put in the `syntax` directory of your [runtimepath](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27runtimepath%27). For the emacs one it seems like you just need to copy that code into your `.emacs` file.